# How to create a data validation list based on certain criteria and data from another workbook?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, spreadsheet

I have two Excel spreadsheet files (2 workbooks), one stores all the data, another wants to create a list based on certain criteria from the data in the previous workbook. Here are the two files:
File A:

```
    A       B
1   Chen    China
2   Li      China
3   Smith   Britain
4   Tanaka  Japan
5   Hironi  Japan
```

On File B, I have two cells:

```
    A       B
    China   ?
```

Cell A1 is a list of countries such as China, Japan, etc. I have no problem creating this. But B1 needs to have a data validation list that reads data from File A. The list should not list all the items but based on the value of A1, say if A1 is China, B1 will have a list of two names: Chen and Li.

I can achieve it if all the sheets in the same workbook, but no matter how I tried, I couldn’t figure it out how to do that with separate spreadsheet files. I prefer using formula, but if necessary writing VBA code is also not a problem.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure where you are with your formula but with a couple of tweaks this `array` should work, or at least provide a basis for you to solve your problem. The tweaks are (1) switch columns so the country is colA; (2) replace `data file.xls` and the `sheet no.` with your own; (3) drop the formula in B1 and drag it to (say) F1. Then you will need to edit the row reference in the formula by adding 1 each time i.e. the row ref in B1 will be `ROW(1:1)`.... C1 will be `ROW(2:2)` etc

> =IF(ISERROR( INDEX('[data file.xls]Sheet7'!$A$1:$B$5,SMALL(IF('[data
>   file.xls]Sheet7'!$A$1:$A$5=$A$1,ROW('[data
>   file.xls]Sheet7'!$A$1:$A$5)),ROW(1:1)),2)),"---", INDEX('[data
>   file.xls]Sheet7'!$A$1:$B$5,SMALL(IF('[data
>   file.xls]Sheet7'!$A$1:$A$5=$A$1,ROW('[data
>   file.xls]Sheet7'!$A$1:$A$5)),ROW(1:1)),2))

Remember this is an `array` formula so `shift`+ `control`+ `enter`. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I got your point, but one problem remains - how to put the formula into a data validation list which seems not able to contain an array formula.

Comment: Have you tried leaving the formula in a helper cell and let the data validation refer to that cell?

Comment: Thanks again for the answer, but one helper cell is apparently not enough instead you need a range of cells to which the data validation list can refer. I changed to use VBA and it turns out much easier in this scenario.

Comment: Well the main thing is that you got there in the end. Maybe you can post the code.